# Change the index position to 0 match with condition in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array like

```
[openingTimes(id: 389A2E43-65C3-4555-8878-D63E1D9BE664, day: "Sunday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"), openingTimes(id: 50041432-5709-4F9D-BCF0-935504741037, day: "Monday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"), openingTimes(id: 5A7F2A66-DABD-470D-9C5B-3E4EA0BA38F6, day: "Tuesday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"),openingTimes(id: 9D977AE4-BC50-4D3E-9E36-6A3118A54F77, day: "Wednesday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"), openingTimes(id: 343E3918-14A3-411A-A43F-EBF1D6F13B58, day: "Thursday", workingHours: "1PM-5PM 8PM-12PM"), openingTimes(id: B658E07B-BBC8-4802-8C0A-DA79A0871BF8, day: "Friday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"), openingTimes(id: 29A15DC2-E0A1-46DA-A022-CF6102B239F4, day: "Saturday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM")]
```

I need to change the index position to 0 when the day match with current day? How can we achieve this?
currently i am using below function taking current day

```
func getTodayWeekDay()-> String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    let weekDay = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    return weekDay
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get today's day? Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. What do you mean by "change index position to `0`"
? There is no index at all in your question. Do you want top move your element to the start of the collection if the day matches today's weekday?

Comment: Do you want to shift the array so the current day is at position 0?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes

Comment: @Rob. I getting today day function I need to do  based on today's day i need to rearrange the index positon to 0 match with today

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes That only i want move the elment to top of the collection

Comment: @Ben10 So, if in this array you have 4 same days, which one do you want to place at zero index? It is still unclear, but I think what you are asking is sorting on the basis of current day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the first index where day is equal to today's weekday, get the sequence from that index, remove that subrange and insert the contents of the subsequence at the startIndex. Note that it is Swift convention to name your structures starting with a lowercase letter:

---

```
extension Date {
    static var weekDay: String { Date().weekDay }
    var weekDay: String { Formatter.weekDay.string(from: self) }
}
```

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let weekDay: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "cccc"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
struct OpeningTimes {
    let id: String
    let day: String
    let workingHours: String
}
```

---

```
var openingTimes: [OpeningTimes] = [
    .init(id: "389A2E43-65C3-4555-8878-D63E1D9BE664", day: "Sunday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"),
    .init(id: "50041432-5709-4F9D-BCF0-935504741037", day: "Monday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"),
    .init(id: "5A7F2A66-DABD-470D-9C5B-3E4EA0BA38F6", day: "Tuesday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"),
    .init(id: "9D977AE4-BC50-4D3E-9E36-6A3118A54F77", day: "Wednesday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"),
    .init(id: "343E3918-14A3-411A-A43F-EBF1D6F13B58", day: "Thursday", workingHours: "1PM-5PM 8PM-12PM"),
    .init(id: "B658E07B-BBC8-4802-8C0A-DA79A0871BF8", day: "Friday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"),
    .init(id: "29A15DC2-E0A1-46DA-A022-CF6102B239F4", day: "Saturday", workingHours: "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM")
]

if let index = openingTimes.firstIndex(where: {$0.day == Date.weekDay}) {
    let subsequence = openingTimes[index...]
    openingTimes.removeSubrange(index...)
    openingTimes.insert(contentsOf: subsequence, at: 0)
}

openingTimes //  {id "29A15DC2-E0A1-46DA-A022-CF6102B239F4", day "Saturday", workingHours "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"}, {id "389A2E43-65C3-4555-8878-D63E1D9BE664", day "Sunday", workingHours "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"}, {id "50041432-5709-4F9D-BCF0-935504741037", day "Monday", workingHours "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"}, {id "5A7F2A66-DABD-470D-9C5B-3E4EA0BA38F6", day "Tuesday", workingHours "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"}, {id "9D977AE4-BC50-4D3E-9E36-6A3118A54F77", day "Wednesday", workingHours "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"}, {id "343E3918-14A3-411A-A43F-EBF1D6F13B58", day "Thursday", workingHours "1PM-5PM 8PM-12PM"}, {id "B658E07B-BBC8-4802-8C0A-DA79A0871BF8", day "Friday", workingHours "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"}]
```

Comment: but i need below format openingTimes //  [{id "B658E07B-BBC8-4802-8C0A-DA79A0871BF8", day "Friday", workingHours "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"}, {id "389A2E43-65C3-4555-8878-D63E1D9BE664", day "Saturday", workingHours "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"}, {id "50041432-5709-4F9D-BCF0-935504741037", day "Sunday", workingHours "11AM-4PM 8PM-11PM"}, {id "5A7F2A66-DABD-470D-9C5B-3E4EA0BA38F6",

Comment: @Ben10 you just need to get the sequence from that index, remove that subrange and insert the contents of the subsequence at the startIndex

Comment: Personally, I would probably use `Calendar` to get the weekday and then used that to index `DateFormatter.standaloneWeekdaySymbols`.

Comment: @Sulthan That depends if the weekday is localized or not

Comment: @LeoDabus Why? That can be modified by `DateFormatter.locale`.

Comment: Why would a need all weekday names if I only need today’s weekday name ? The collection itself is already sorted